# Recommendation for a good book on first order logic w.r.t inductive logic programming

Tags: books, advice-and-nonuniformity, logic-programming

I have had 10 days to read up on Computational Logic but the books I am following are only succeeding in confusing me. I find most of text's ( Niehuys-Cheng & de Wolf 1997, De Raedt 2008, Lloyd 1987 ) very wordy. None of them provide will worked out examples for, say, SLD-resolution. So I was wondering if anyone knows of a good book with nice examples which explain first order logic in an intuitive manner ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

How about [foundations of disjunctive logic programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262121654)? While rather old (1992), it has over 100 examples. For instance, SLI and SLD resolutions are discussed and exemplified in section 4.2.

PS: You may read some parts of that section on [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=kCC4j6hUTgYC&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q&f=false).